# Intellij is incorrectly formatting my `.yml` file, I cannot see any errors in my style settings. how can I fix it?

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

Intellij keeps formatting my `spotbugs.yml` file incorrectly, and so breaking the github action.
I cannot figure out why it's doing this:

[image]

It was working fine last week, I haven't made any changes to the formatting config, but now, every time I change focus from the file Intellij auto-formats like this, then saves it. How can I fix it?

The thing I don't get is what it's formatting to appears to be invalid `yaml`, right?

Comment: YAML is generally horrible when indented with anything but 2 spaces. Just look at how the level of the keys in a step is not aligned to 4 spaces because `-` with following space takes up two columns and you don't want to have more spaces behind it. While it is certainly not okay what IntelliJ is doing, I assume it has to do with YAML value alignment being fundamentally at odds with indentation settings, and I would advise to simply use 2 spaces for indentation in YAML. This will probably fix the confused formatter (but I didn't test it).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: This appears to have been the problem, the `yaml` style settings were set to indent 4 spaces. setting it to 2 spaces fixed the problem. Care to write an answer I can accept?

Comment: I had this issue due to an `.editorconfig` with `[*] indent_size = 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML has a syntax that makes it incompatible with indentation that is not 2 spaces. With 4 spaces, you have:

```yaml
droggel:
    jug:
        - sequence item: with indentation
          this line: isn't aligned to four spaces
          nor are further indented lines:
               if you indent relative four spaces
    spam:
    - same: problem
      without: indenting the sequence item
```

This makes it hard for code formatters to get it right. Proper alignment would mean:

```yaml
droggel:
    jug:
        -   three spaces after the sequence item indicator.
            that's horrible, nobody does that.
    spam:
      - alternatively this.
        nobody does this either and it breaks
      - - with nested sequences
```

I assume some bug in IntelliJ causes the formatter to be confused because of this. Generally it would be better to just use 2 space indentation which seems far more natural due to the problems described above. That should avoid confusing the formatter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration that fix list values. In Editor-> Code Style->Yaml

```
"Indent sequence value"
```